# How to break a long with statement in python

Tags: python

I have a line of code in python like this:

```
with long_name_function(p) as a, other_long_name_function():
```

and I want to break it in multiple lines, because is too long, I could use backslashes, but they are considered a bad practice. I also could use contextlib.nested, but is deprecated, is there any other alternative?

Comment: backslashes are not considered bad practice, it's just preferred to use brackets or commas for breaking up code into different lines when possible.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This disregards the premise of the question but I would actually recommend using backslashes in this case:

```
with really_really_long_name_function(p) as f1, \
        other_really_really_long_name_function() as f2:
    pass
```

As @JonClements said, you can't use brackets or commas in this case, there's no alternative so backslashes are the way to go and the code looks pretty clean IMO.

Comment: Yup - Since parentheses can't be used (can't think of a properly justifiable reason why though) then yeah, I reckon backslashing it is easily the most readable and practical in this case....

Comment: Note that as written this example throws a warning running through pep8: `E127 continuation line over-indented for visual indent`.  If you back off the the indent by 1 space to be 4 spaces, then it throws `E125 continuation line with same indent as next logical line`.  It seems like the cleanest compromise is to just give 8 spaces of indentation which throws no messages in pep8.

Comment: @jamylak That's correct.  Of course all three run correctly, but 8 spaces is the only one that passes pep8 without warning.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to avoid backslashes, you can alias the long names:

```
lnf = long_name_function
olnf = other_long_name_function
with lnf(p) as a, olnf():
    # ...
```

or you could nest the statements:

```
with long_name_function(p) as a:
    with other_long_name_function():
        pass
```

You do *not* want to use `contextlib.nested()`; there are several problems with it that directly led to its deprecation. Earlier context managers are not covered for problems with later context managers in the nesting, for example.

Comment: @JaredGoguen: you can put the expression that creates or names the context manager in parentheses, but that just becomes really ugly.